# ubuntu can't get lighttpd server to start with my [ipaddress]:[port[

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd

I'm trying to run lighttpd on ubuntu in parallel with Apache, but it won't startup on the ip address and server that I have specified. I have the following configuration:

```
server.document-root       = "/var/www"
server.port               = 8000
server.bind = "#.#.#.#"
```

where the #'s are replace by the IP address of my server.

However, when I restart I get the following error:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
Syntax OK
 * Stopping web server lighttpd
   ...done.
Syntax OK
 * Starting web server lighttpd
2010-09-16 19:43:41: (network.c.345) can't bind to port: #.#.#.# 8000 Cannot assign requested address 
   ...fail!
```

I'd like to be able to access the server with the url: http://#.#.#.#:8000/index.html

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What IP address are you using? You can only bind to local IP addresses (127.*.*.*, 192.168.*.* (or 10.*.*.*) and the public IP address).

Comment: Don't remember now. I just went ahead and wrote a simple Python-based webserver that only understands 1 URL on port 81. It does exactly, what I need it to do.

Comment: You could also use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for a bit more configurability.

Comment: [It seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730280/ubuntu-cant-get-lighttpd-server-to-start-with-my-ipaddressport#comment22659917_15829203) this can now be closed as *too localized*. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't use as local address a thing like `#.#.#.#`, I hope was a placeholder.

Comment: I believe it was a placeholder, but can't even remember why I asked this question now.